# Proper media-type for a Twitter tweet?

Tags: api, twitter, mime-types, content-type

What is the proper [media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) to use for a status update (aka "Tweet") from the Twitter API?

For some background, I am writing an API that will accept an array of documents, each with a media type (e.g. `image/jpeg`, `text/html`, `application/pdf`, etc). I want Tweet JSON to be in the array of accepted types.

I was hoping for a vnd. type but didn't see one on the [huge list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) I found. Am I approaching this correctly?

My best stab would be: `application/vnd.twitter.status+json`

Comment: or possibly `message/x.twitter.status+json` as it's not a registered type

Comment: The problem is that x. types are "not recommended" since 1996 and "strongly discouraged" since 2013. There are also many vnd. types in wide use that are not registered (e.g. android types).